# How to set cookies on the entire domain name from Java Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I have one servlet, located at `site.com/foo/BarServlet`. This servlet is the one which is responsible for setting cookies. The problem is, when I set the cookies, their path is set at `/foo`. Does this mean that any servlets located at `site.com/SomeOtherServlet` are not going to be able to access those cookies?

If so, is there a way I could set the cookies on the entire domain instead? If I try to do `cookie.setPath("/")`, then for some reason, when I try to remove the cookie via `cookie.setMaxAge(0)`, that has no effect and it remains in place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem was solved by doing `cookie.setPath("/")` both when setting, and when removing the cookie. Previously, I was only doing this when setting, but not when removing. Hence, the cookie was not getting removed. Now, its working across the whole domain.